# link to .msg file open in outlook

Tags: html, google-chrome, outlook

Good morning,

I have a file stored on the http server called MNF.msg I have created the link to the file:

and when I click on the link Chrome is downloading the msg file. Is there any possibility that after clicking on the link the message will be opened with Outlook (which is default mail application)?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved it by using "always open files of this type" option in Google Chrome which can be activated after downloading the file for the first time.